# Validating XML file with XSD and lxml in Python throws AssertionError

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I am trying to validate a couple of XML files against their XSD (xml schema defintion). If the xml file is not valid I would like to show the reason. I am using:

- Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10 (I wish I could use it on Linux)
- The [lxml Library](https://lxml.de/validation.html)

I got the following examples from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_howto.asp) in order to check my code. But running my code results in the following error:

```
AssertionError: Element 'note': No matching global declaration available for the validation root., line 2
```

The error goes away as soon as I replace this part of the XSD:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

with

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error in the first place?

### My Code

```py
import os
import sys
from lxml import etree

class Validator:

    def __init__(self, xsd_path):
        parsed_xsd = etree.parse(xsd_path)  # Parse content of xsd file to ElementTree object
        self.xsdschema = etree.XMLSchema(parsed_xsd)

    def validate_xml(self, xml_path):
        parsed_xml = etree.parse(xml_path)
        # result = self.xsdschema.validate(parsed_xml)
        # return result
        self.xsdschema.assert_(parsed_xml)

# Get current path of script
SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xsd_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, 'note.xsd'))
xml_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, 'note_example.xml'))

validator = Validator(xsd_path)
validator.validate_xml(xml_path)
```

**note.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- Here is the problematic part -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<!-- End of problematic part -->

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**note_example.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: change schema with <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> and it should works

Comment: That did not work, same error occurs.

Comment: I've used this command "xmllint --schema file.xsd file.xml --noout" with your source schema I got the same error as yours, but with the modified schema it works. So, probably the problem it is not in the schema nor in xml file, but elsewhere

Comment: The problem is relative to the namespace, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411742/xml-schema-no-matching-global-declaration-available-for-the-validation-root could help